# Ssrs report add hyperlink to field where hyperlink URL is from another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Hi I have two fields from my crm and in my ssrs report I need to have a field value displayed as a hyperlink so that when user clicks, it takes them to the URL which is populated in another field that is in my dataset.

Is this possible ?
Field A = "hello world"
Field b= "www.google.com"

So in report when user clicks hello world in results they are directed to google.com.

Could some one please tell how I could do this ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239346.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This should be quite easy to achieve.  I'll demonstrate with Report Builder 2016 and place the hyperlink in a table but the idea is the same with any version of report builder and any target location on the report.

1. Assuming you have a dataset where the first row has the values 'Hello World' (column named 'text') and 'www.google.com' (column named 'link'), set the display text in the table cell to 'text':
   [image]
2. Right click on the textbox cell and select 'Text box properties':
   [image]
3. Click the action tab. Select 'Go to URL' and click the 'fx' button to set the URL expression:
   [image]
4. Append "http://" to your link so that it will resolve as a web address correctly like:

   ="http://" & Fields!link.Value
5. Upon running the report, I am able to click the "hello world" text and it opens a webpage to "www.google.ca".